# I found a vulnerability on a website, how do I approach the company about it?

Tags: security

This is the first time I have found a vulnerability on a website.

A client just wanted some data scraped from an auction website.

while collecting the clients data I noticed that if something sold you would need to buy a yearly subscription to see how much it sold for, glossary, item info etc.

But I found that the price it sold for is still being injected by JavaScript but not being displayed and this is a feature the ask customers to pay for.

Just wanted to get advice from people who usually test vulnerabilities on how they approach the companies about the vulnerability.

Thank in advance..

Answer (score 1):

First of all, StackOverflow is more focused on software development, the [Security StackExchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/) would be more appropriate to ask such questions.

If I understood the context correctly, you do not have any security audit contract that explicitly allows you to look for vulnerabilities. Yet, you were missioned to **scrape** their website, so looking at their code is part of what you had to do. I would say the answer depends on whether you were in the scope of your mission or not. Did you notice this flaw without even trying or did you dig more that you should have ?

If this flaw appeared to you while you were doing the job you were asked to do, then I would say it's pretty safe to just email them in the the context of your job.

If this vulnerability is too far out of your scope, then be careful because if they don't like it, worst case scenario they could very well pressure your company to fire you or something (they would be total idiots to do so, but better be careful when dealing with security). If you are in this scenario, I suggest you report the vulnerability "anonymously" (doesn't have to be over complicated, simply use an email address not containing your name or the name of your company and you'll be alright). You could also check out bug bounty platforms to see if they are affiliated to any program. Also some platforms such as openbugbounty provide [ways to report vulnerabilities "anonymously"](https://www.openbugbounty.org/report/).

In my experience, I've never seen any company being total jerk and going against someone reporting a vulnerability in good faith, companies are generally concerned about security and will thank you for telling them there's something wrong.

Either way, try to be as descriptive as possible so they can understand the issue and fix it.

Just stating the obvious here : don't disclose this vulnerability publicly or you're exposing yourself to some big trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will definitely report it anonymously. I can across it by complete accident with the data scrape. It is only info their paid clients should have. But thanks again.. and will post security question on security exchange next time.